# Pass pug variable inside function

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to pass a variable in my Pug code to an `onSubmit` event in a `form` element. Here's my code for that:

```
each post in posts    
   p(class="postContent") #{post.content}

   form(method='post' id="likeForm" target="invis" onSubmit="addLike(`${post._id}`)")
```

As you can see, in the `addLike` function, I'm trying to pass in the `post._id` variable. The variable is very much defined, and the function works, but I seem to be passing the variable into the function incorrectly. I also tried `addLike(#{post._id})` but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to pass the post._id variable as a string argument to the addLike function using template literals (${post._id}) in a JavaScript event handler for the onSubmit attribute of the form.
The correct way to pass the variable in this case is to remove the ` and ${} and just use post._id like this:
onSubmit="addLike(post._id)"
You also don't need to use #{post._id}

Comment: Hey, this doesn't work, I've also tried this. I get an error stating `post is not defined`, so your method seems to be wrong somehow.